# .slideToggle class individually based on .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically trying to write something like this.  Click .button and it .slideToggle(s) it's associated .box Div.  Nesting them inside a container div to try different methods.

I feel stupid, this has been asked many times.  I've tried at least a dozen none of which I can get to work.

Code is here.

http://jsfiddle.net/BurRQ/25/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#" class="toggle">TOGGLE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `.parent` method to move back into your header before trying to use `.next`.

http://jsfiddle.net/BurRQ/26/

## Before

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.box').slideToggle("slow");
}); // .click
```

## After

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.box').slideToggle("slow");
}); // .click
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, here are three (since I can give them a name)

The family method: `$(this).parent().siblings('.box').slideToggle();`

The closest find method: `$(this).closest('.container').find('.box').slideToggle();`

The next parent method: `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();`